# Java dependency management for nodejs developers

Tags: java, node.js, maven, dependency-management

I have been writing code in node.js now for sometime, and node has this nice package manager called `npm`
To install a package, I simple do `npm install pkg-name` and there it is, in my `node_modules` folder. There is a `package.json` file with all my dependencies listed.

I need to write some Java code and Maven seems to be a popular dependency management tool for Java. Although, I had a bit of a tough time wrapping my head around it.

*I want to know what are the analogous things in `Maven` to `npm`.*

So, what's the equivalent to `npm install pkg-name` in Maven?
Where do I find the dependencies? `npm` has a nice web ui, something like that for Maven?

Any hello world projects for Maven that I can see?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, maven does more that npm, by that it can manage not only dependencies, but also the entire build and deployment process. it also integertad with most IDE's like idea or eclipse to make life much easier.
I suggest you'll start with some maven tutorial, like [this one](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), it will give you a good grasp of how to start

regarding hello world project - one feature you have in maven is to create a project from an archetype - you can try that out, will give you a good way to look how maven configuration looks like

Comment: Is there a dedicated folder in maven where all the dependencies go? Something like `node_modules` in node?

Comment: the jars are stored on a maven repository on your computer. When you deploy your project, it will be deployed along with it, depending on your packaging method (rpm, jar, etc.)

Comment: This might be a bit unrelated but I create a project using mvn achetype, I am able to run it in my IDE but get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error when I try to run  the jar by doing  `java -cp target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.jk.app.App` What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 1):

In maven you don't install packages, but you write all your dependencies in pom.xml. And those are downloaded and used during the build (when you do e.g. `mvn clean install`)

pom.xml is a description of your project (e.g. it contains what dependencies are used, which compiler version, what is the project name, resulting binaries, etc.), there is a description of POM with examples here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html